# Quarkus : Change OpenApi authorization url at runtime

Tags: runtime, openapi, quarkus

I am currently experimenting with quarkus and cannot find a way to change some openapi information at runtime (here, I want the authorization url to change depending on the environment).

It should be possible by using OASFilter and feeding information from environment variables but OASFilter seems to be initialized at build time. I added a log in the filterSecurityScheme method and the log is displayed at build (by quarkus-maven-plugin) and then never displayed at runtime.

The code is pretty simple :

```java
public class OASSecurityConfiguration implements OASFilter {
    @Override
    public SecurityScheme filterSecurityScheme(final SecurityScheme securityScheme) {
        securityScheme.getFlows().
                       getImplicit().
                       setAuthorizationUrl(ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url", String.class)+"/protocol/openid-connect/auth");
        return securityScheme;
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to change openapi specs at runtime from environment variables or to prevent the OASFilter to be initialized at build time ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since Quarkus v2 there is now a config option `quarkus.smallrye-openapi.always-run-filter` ([docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/openapi-swaggerui#quarkus-smallrye-openapi_quarkus.smallrye-openapi.always-run-filter)) that enables you to run the OASfilter everytime the openapi document is served.